# Finding .php files with certain variable declaration (string search) on command line (Shell)

Tags: linux, file, centos, command-line-interface, devops

I'm attempting to find all .PHP files that are in certain depth of a directory (at least 4 levels down, but not more than 5 levels in).

I'm logged into my Centos server with root authority via shell.

The string I want to search for is:

```
$slides='';
```

What I have in front of me.. I would expect it to work. I tried to escape the $ with a \ (I thought perhaps it works like regex, needing special chars excluded). I tried without the `=''` portion, or tried adding `\'\'` to that part.. or remove the `=''` altogether to simplify. nothing.

```
find . -maxdepth 5 -mindepth 4 -type f -name ‘*.php’ -print  | xargs grep "\$slides=’’" *
```

I'm already running it under the directory under which I want to recursively search.

Also - I have the filter to look for *.php only but I still get a bunch of directory names in the return with a warning that says `grep: [dir_name]: Is a directory`

Clearly I am missing something here as far as syntax of grep command goes, or how the filter works here. I use grep more in PHP so this is quite a transition for me!

Comment: Try `find . -maxdepth 5 -mindepth 4 -type f -name '*.php' -print0  | xargs -0 grep "\$slides=''"` or `find . -maxdepth 5 -mindepth 4 -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep "\$slides=''" {} \;`

Comment: Wow your first one worked like a charm. I will have to google more to see what those other items you put there does! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

So you were almost right. The problem looks to have been the `grep` part of the command

```
grep "\$slides=''" *
```

Namely the `*` was the issue. From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set (see The Set
> Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’.
> If one of these characters appears, and is not quoted, then the word
> is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted
> list of filenames matching the pattern

When you piped the found files with `find` into `xargs` and attempted to `grep` them with `*`, `grep` would have interpreted this as you wanting to find the string `$slides=''` in a list of filenames/directories returned by the glob `*`, and you cannot `grep` directories without supplying the `-r` flag to `grep`, so it returned an error.

Instead, what you wanted to do is pipe the found files with `find` into `xargs` so it can add the list of filenames to the `grep` command, as that's what `xargs` does. From the [xargs manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

> xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which
> can  be  protected with  double or single quotes or a backslash) or
> newlines, and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more
> times with any  initial- arguments  followed  by items read from
> standard input.  Blank lines on the standard input are ignored.

Making the correct command

```
find . -maxdepth 5 -mindepth 4 -type f -name '*.php' -print0  | xargs -0 grep "\$slides=''"
```

Using the `-print0` flag in `find`, and the `-0` flag in `xargs`, to use [NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) as the delimiter, in case any filenames contained newlines.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use shell_exec from your PHP code, it is a program execution function which allows you to run a command like 'ls -al' in the operating system shell and get the result returned into a variable. Querystrings are not commands you can use in this way.

Do you mean running PHP from the command line so that it runs from the shell, not from the web server:

## php -r 'echo "hello world\n";'

If you run PHP 4.3 and above, you can use the PHP Command Line Interface (CLI) which can also execute scripts stored in files. Have a look at the syntax and examples at: http://php.net/features.commandline

Comment: I'm running from CLI (shell) with root access. Not looking to enable shell commands from PHP, security wise will prefer not to let that happen.

Comment: Also above are clearly shell commands, not PHP.